# Copying specific set of rows from one table to another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables both having same column and but different no of rows.

```
Generation
{Date,
location,
location_id,
turbine_id,
Generation,}

Generation_copy
{date,
location,
location_id,
turbine_id,
Generation}
```

In Generation table i have 5000 rows which have rows up to date  and in Generation_copy i have only 4500 rows  which i  haven't updated the table for last one week

Now i need to fill the unfilled  500 rows into table   Generation_copy.

Comment: here you need to sync these 2 tables?

Comment: yes exactly,i need to  update the generation_copy table ,so that  i can add two more columns in future.

Comment: is there any PK or Unique column in Generation table..?

Comment: yes i have combined unique key for both date and location , i have  also tried insert query , but i received duplication error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 insert into generation_copy 
  select * from generation where (date,location)
  not in 
 (select date,location from generation_copy )
```

Comment: thanks a lot  sola !! it will help me a lot in other cases while updating other tables in my database .

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

DELETE FROM Generation_copy;

-- Then just recopy the values.

INSERT INTO Generation_copy (Date,location,location_id,turbine_id,Generation) 
SELECT Date,location,location_id,turbine_id,Generation from Generation

Comment: okay i will try !!i have assigned unique key combined for bothe date and location , so while running the insert i got duplication error  ! ! is there any alternative solution